# export .db table to excel with header/column and values

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite

Hi All: Uisng SQLiteDataReader i'm getting the table values but i'm not getting the column value using  **SQLiteDataReader GetName**

My goal is to i want data with column name in excel file which is same as query then followed by the table values. wWhat is the mistake here? thanks

I think i'm making mistake in the for loop?

```
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1]; // (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    xlWorkSheet.Name = "Stats";

    string cs = @"C:\\db_test\\Database.db";
    string data = String.Empty;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\db_test\\Database.db"))
    {
        con.Open();

        //string stm = "SELECT Oid from Stats";
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT");
        query.Append("[Oid], [CreatedOn], [OrderOid] ");
        query.Append(",[OrderLineOid], [OrderNumber], [Product] ");
        query.Append(",[PaperTypeName], [OutputProfile], [OutputProfileChannel] ");
        query.Append("FROM Stats");

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query.ToString(), con))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
            
                while (rdr.Read()) // Reading Rows
                {
                    var columns = new List<string>();
                    

                    for (j = 0; j <= rdr.FieldCount - 1; j++) // Looping throw colums
                    {
                        columns.Add(rdr.GetName(j));
                        data = rdr.GetValue(j).ToString();
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;

                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) +"\\"+ "Statictics_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xls";
    
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: You're storing the column names into `columns` but you're not using them anymore. You're just writing `data` -which only contains the values-  to your Excel file.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ : thanks for poinging the mistake, How can write the 'GetName' into to the file? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you likely got the solution you needed from the comments on your post, but I'll offer another. I maintain a library, [Sylvan.Data.Excel](https://github.com/markpflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel) that will be easier and much faster than Excel interop. The library is open source and has a permissive license (MIT).

Writing to an .xlsx file only takes a couple lines of code.

```
SQLiteDataReader rdr = GetData(); // get your data reader from Sqlite

using var writer = ExcelDataWriter.Create("mydata.xlsx");
writer.Write(rdr, "Stats");
```

While my library supports reading most common Excel formats, it only supports writing .xlsx files. It is the [fastest Excel library for .NET](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/ExcelWriterBenchmarks.md). For comparison, using Excel interop (the code your provided above) takes ~15 minutes to write the 65k records that Sylvan can write in less than half a second. My library also doesn't require that Excel be installed on the machine, its only dependency is the core .NET runtime libraries.